# From Android app A, how to open non main activity in app B?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have app A and app B, both APK are generated with the same code base. App B is generated with a different flavor than app A, hence they have have different applicationId.

From app A, I'd like to start Activity1 in app B.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.packagename.appb", "com.packagename.appb.Activity1"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm getting the exception

> ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.packagename.appb/com.packagename.appb.Activity1}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

But Activity1 is already declared in the manifest because it's an activity also available in app A

What should I do ?

Comment: `Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.packagename.appb");`= will this help?

Comment: Using this method, it starts app B's main activity, whereas I'd like to start an other activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following approach if it fits.
Create launcher intent:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.packagename.appb");
```

Put some data inside that `Intent` check on MainActivity `onStart` method, if data is there move to desired `Activity` and finally remove data from `Intent`. For example:

```
intent.putExtra("activityB", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside B app `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   boolean shouldStartB = intent.getBooleanExtra("activityB", false);
    if(shouldStartB) {
      //start new Activity 
      intent.removeExtra("activityB"); //Don't forget to remove extra to prevent bug
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the other app packageName/ class directly. for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app");
```

You'd probably want to put a try/catch around for a ActivityNotFoundException for when the application is not installed

Comment: If I use Intent intent = new Intent("com.packagename.appb.Activity1"); I get an ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: did you test using use the setClassName method?

Comment: Yes, same exception: ActivityNotFoundException